# Implementation uses too much memory

Tags: performance-tuning, memory

Code shows memory error for higher values of the variable `Numofbits`. I can only go until 4.

```
Numofbits = 4;
NumOfFunc = 15;
AllFunc = BitXor @@@ Subsets[Transpose@Tuples[{0, 1}, Numofbits], {1, Numofbits}];
AllStr = Tuples[{0, 1}, 2^Numofbits];
BigTable = Table[If[AllFunc[[k, i]] == AllStr[[j, i]], 1, 0], {i, 1, 2^Numofbits}, {j, 1, 2^(2^Numofbits)}, {k, 1, NumOfFunc}];
SumOnEach = Total[BigTable, {1}];
Gretst = Table[If[SumOnEach[[i, j]] > 2^(Numofbits - 1), SumOnEach[[i, j]], 2^Numofbits - SumOnEach[[i, j]]], {i, 1, 2^(2^Numofbits)}, {j, 1, NumOfFunc}];
AllSuccProb = Total[Gretst, {2}]/(2^Numofbits*NumOfFunc);

MaxSuccProb = Max[AllSuccProb]
(* Out: 5/8 *)
```

Comment: `AllStr` contains `2^2^n` elements, and thus requires 32GB of RAM by itself for `Numofbits = 5` and 128 exabytes of RAM for `Numofbits = 6` (or more, I was assuming they'd be packed doubles/machine integers at 8 bytes per element). You'll have to rewrite your problem to avoid expanding it out this far. What is the question you're trying to answer?

Comment: @eyorble oh no...I'm calculating the success probabilities for encoding an n bit string to a single bit and then retrieving a given function from it (functions are defined using the AllFunc variable...)